# Speed up dynamic view creation for android

Tags: android, performance, view

I have created an android app that works as designed. However, onCreate() uses dynamic(not xml) to create 80% of my layout,which are consist of buttons. It takes about 3-4 second to build the entire layout, which is too slow. Is there any suggestions to speed up this process?

Things I tried:
1. using fewer view objects, it has not improved the speed and using listview and linearview had very minimal gains
2. I tried moving some of my to onResume(), no gain
3. using serializer to keep my view in sharedpreferences did not work

Are there any ways to speed up dynamic view creation?

Comment: Please provide your onCreate() code.

Comment: Have you compared speeds of dynamic inflation verses using xml?  Maybe there is something else slowing you down.  Also, I've noticed on ICS phones, that it takes longer for your layout to show up on first launch (usually a second or two), when comparing it to gingerbread phones.

Comment: I have used microtime and log to compare speed of different parts of the code, the view part takes 1100 microsecond as the rest of the code takes 200 to 300 microseconds only.

Comment: here is a link to my code: [link](http://farzad.devbro.com/code.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you thought about using a List View and inflating a custom view from xml into the convert views which are recycled?

I don't know if this would work in your case since I don't know what your code does but this seems like the proper place ot use an adapter and some sort of List element

Comment: I have tried this. So far the performance is better than before :) recycling views have been much more useful than creating the whole thing at one point.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put all code from layout inside a runOnUiThread() method from Activity. You can use this in onCrete() or onResume() (onResume is called always when Activity came to front). Try like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {          
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do stuff from layout
        }
    });
```

This way, the code will running in a thread and it will free the Activity to show itself.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The drawing of Ui simply takes ages. I am planning to break the UiThread so it runs as two parts to give the illusion of speed.